# How do we center a view horizontally in a container?

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS development and I have a question about alignment. when I want to centre a view horizontally, I find there are two ways (am I wrong?)
1.) Size inspector -> Arrange (position View, I choose centre horizontally 
   in container)
or

2.) Alignment constraint -> horizontally in container

A) What is the difference between these two methods?
B) And when I want to center a view, which one should I implement or should I implement both?

Comment: second option is good enough to keep your view horizontally. And you can change it programatically if needed. I want you to go for second way.

Answer (score 2):

There are really just two things here:

**Autoresizing**(size inspector -> Arrange (position View, I choose centre horizontally in container)

**AutoLayout** (alignment constraint -> horizontally in container)

Autoresizing is basically a collective term for the old way Apple introduced in order to enable developers to build dynamic layouts. The number one usecase to address here was screen rotation. Since when a screen would be rotated (or otherwise resized), the subviews in the screen would most likely hold an incorrect frame (position and size) in the newly sized superview. To address this, Apple introduced a series of enumerable properties (called Autoresizing Masks), that tell the superview to treat a subview in a particular way. Among these are:

Flexible Width/Height, which causes a subview to expand to the fullest width/height available

Flexible Leading/Trailing/Top/Bottom space, which allows a specific edge to be variable, and so forth.

A view could contain any combination of these enum properties.

This was inadequate because, among other shortcomings, it lays down no rules regarding how a view should be layouted (if that's a verb) with respect to its other sibling views. It also required a lot of extra coding to manually resize views on orientation changes.

Here's where AutoLayout entered the picture. Apple built a framework which worked on the basis of constraints - rules that could be applied on views and between views, that would determine how a view would be sized in variable screen sizes. These constraints are structured in a class called NSLayoutConstraint, and each instance (constraint) of this class has the following important properties:

The item (view) on which the constraint is applied
The property of the view (height, width, leading edge, trailing edge, and so on) that the constraint is applicable to
The second item (a sibling or a child or a parent view) to which the constraint is related
The second item's attribute
The multiplier on the constraint: useful in order to specify ratio based constraints
A value (or constant) of the constraint: interestingly, the only property of a constraint that can be changed after instantiation.
A simple example of an NSLayoutConstraint, stated prosaically is: a view's width will be half the the width of its superview multiplied by 60%.

Your AutoLayout based UI would consist of many such constraints, which will all work together to express an unambiguous and non-conflicting UI Layout.

Now the AutoLayout engine, which makes it all work, interacts with views on the screen, calling AutoLayout messages such as layoutSubviews whenever needed in order automatically resize (layout) views whenever changes occur on screen, such as orientation change, a superview getting resized etc.

Constraints are most commonly added by InterfaceBuilder (.xib and .storyboard files), but adding them by code entails the same principle: create an instance of NSLayoutConstraint and add it to the highest view applicable (for eg., if there's a constraint between a child and a parent view, the constraint should be added to the parent view. If there's a constraint between two subviews, again, add it to the parent.)

**B :**
You should implement **AutoLayout**.
No need to implement both.

Comment: You may have missed to answer the second question: ___B)and when I want to center a view, which one should I implement or should I implement both?___

Comment: You should implement AutoLayouts.
No need to implement both

Comment: I haven't added the comment as my question. Your answer lacks the information that the OP wanted to know. You might want to edit the answer with the above comment you just made.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can use both ways, Approach which i recommend You is :

First make it center X to super view and bottom space 0 to bottom layout guide.It could like this:

[image]

Double click the bottom space and change the view bottom to center Y:

[image]

If you don’t use Auto Layout, it’s only one line of code:

```
childView.center = parentView.center
```

If you’re using Auto Layout, you can center your child view inside its parent like this:

```
childView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
childView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Those constraints will automatically update as the available space changes.

**Available from iOS 3.2**

Comment: What's the use of bottom constraint in this scenario? The question was about horizontally centering. You should not bring other constraints forward.